# Where are all possible locations of UninstallString registry entries?

Tags: registry, uninstallation

I'm writing a Wix-based installer that needs to upgrade from older, non-msi-based installations. I'm finding instances of previously installed components by searching directly in the Registry.

To find the uninstaller for a component, I look in

```
 HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyProgram
```

And get the `UninstallString` value. This is fine, but I realised that for a 32 bit install on a 64 bit machine, the entry is actually at

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyProgram
```

Is there anywhere else I ought to be looking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a third entry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Answer (score 2):

I've checked this, and these are the only two locations. The second is used to store 32-bit programs on a 64-bit version of Windows. There are no other cases that need checking.

Comment: Is that "no other cases that need checking [in your particular case]", or "no other cases that need checking [at all]"?