# Open an application's Uninstall Wizard for InstallAware

Tags: delphi, uninstallation, installaware

I have my application that will install another application. This is easily done by running that application's setup.exe with ShellAPI in my program.

However if this external application already exists, I would like to uninstall it first. I can do this myself by opening the Control Panel, finding the application, and then there is some menu options for "Uninstall" or "Repair." Clicking either one will open an InstallAware Wizard for this application.

Can I launch this wizard from my application? The user will still have to click through and confirm everything, but I'm trying to consolidate the steps needed to uninstall and reinstall a fresh/newer version of this external application. I cannot find any thing like an uninstall.exe thing to run. What is executed from the Control Panel link to Uninstall an application?

Comment: Using Task Manager, I was able to find that the application.exe for InstallAware is located at something like `C:\ProgramData\{170EC0AA-F47B-478E-9124-108BF7C47E71}`. If I just run that EXE, the uninstaller opens.

How is this determined and created? There are multiple folders with this kind of GUID. How can I determine which one I need?

Comment: You can get that information from the registry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122761/where-are-all-possible-locations-of-uninstallstring-registry-entries

Comment: Kind of depends on the setup technology use by the other app. You'll need to get more on top of this. What if the version installed is more recent than the version you are supplying. Your users won't like you uninstalling version N+1 and replacing with version N. What if the user wants to keep both version N and N+1. I don't think anyone can give you detailed advice until you have more details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will be able to check the existing version against the version I'm supplying. There is some logic for that.

Comment: @ikathegreat That's hard to do unless you are the installer. Do expect that your detection will fail unless you let the install program perform this logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can find list of installed applications under registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Each application has its own sub-key so you will have to find correct one. Uninstall information is then stored under `UninstallString` value.

There is also possibility that application is installed under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` root key.

However, I would not recommend that you perform un-installation yourself, unless you have some specific reason to do so. Any decent installer should be able to perform upgrade of existing installation, so calling `setup.exe` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Unfortunately these installers are version specific, installing a newer version keeps the older version on the PC and Control Panel Programs list, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: @ikathegreat I find it strange that you dismissed Dalijas answer with just a comment about her last paragraph, while the actual answer to your question is in the very first paragraphs. The Uninstallstring tells you exactly how to fire up the uninstaller wizard. Before you call the uninstaller you may want to check the DisplayVersion. You need to traverse trough the nodes in the Uninstall hive to find the application you are looking for (or all versions of it), but that is exactly what the Control Panel applet is doing.

Comment: I can see why running newer setup alone will not solve your issue. I have slightly modified my recommendation about not doing un-installation yourself, but I decided to leave it as part of the answer as guide to others that may be in slightly different situation. Anyway, solution to your problem is in first part of my answer.